# Switch Statement Prints Incorrect Case?

Tags: java

I have read some code about Switch statement in Java Language.
I noted that written the next code, I have this output:

> FEBO SERR **JANUO** **January** 2

Code:

```
    int month = 2;
    String monthString = "";
    switch (month) {
        case 2:
            monthString = "FEB";
            System.out.print("FEBO ");
        default:
            monthString = "ERROR";
            System.out.println("SERR ");
        case 1:
            monthString = "January";
            System.out.println("JANUO ");
            break;
    }

    System.out.print(monthString+ " ");
    System.out.print(month);
```

I  hoped  the next output really:

> FEBO SERR **FEB** 2

Why I got that first output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because month is `2`. You get the second output because you have no `break` for `case 2` (or `default`) so the statements fallthrough.

Comment: In switch, each of the cases should end with `break` statement. If you didn't put a `break` , all the cases will be applied. That is why you are having this kind of output.

Comment: Ok. I can get a simple answer: if a case not ends in a **break** statement  all cases are applied! Also each cases should ends  with break!  Haha

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if I understand what you want but I think this is what you want:

```
    int month = 1;
    String monthString = "";
    switch (month) {
        case 1:
            monthString = "JAN";
            System.out.println("JANUO ");
            break;
        case 2:
            monthString = "FEB";
            System.out.println("FEBO ");
            break;
        default:
            monthString = "ERROR";
            System.out.println("SERR ");
            break;
    }

    System.out.print("SERR " + monthString+ " ");
    System.out.print(month);
```

Your problem was that you forgot to put the `break;` after each cases. Also, I didnt see any purpose of why you didnt put it into the correct order and (I think?) you did a typo at `System.out.print("FEBO ");` based on the other ones, it should be `System.out.println("FEBO ");` and finally, since you mentioned of wanting `SERR` in each output I adjusted that for you.

**Reminder:** println will print your text AND a new line (\n) while print wont print any.

Answer (score 0):

Add break at the end of each case.

```
switch(condition) {
   case VALUE1:
          // do something
          break;
   default:
          // do default something
}
```